# Can't find the boolean logic to make this work

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, boolean-expression

I'm trying to make the condition that if the [0][0] entry in the array is not equal to 1 or 2 the program prints an error message. I can't get it to work, and I know it's because I can't get the logic correct.

```
try:
    with open(input_script) as input_key:
        for line in input_key.readlines():
            x=[item for item in line.split()]
            InputKey.append(x)
    if InputKey[0][0] == 1 or 2:     #This is where my condition is being tested.
        print '.inp file succesfully imported' #This is where my success (or fail) print comes out.
    else:
        print 'failed'
except IOError:
    print '.inp file import unsuccessful. Check that your file-path is valid.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` condition is evaluated as:

```
if (InputKey[0][0] == 1) or 2:
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if (InputKey[0][0] == 1) or True:
```

which will always evaluated to `True`.

---

You should use:

```
if InputKey[0][0] == 1 or InputKey[0][0] == 2:
```

or

```
if InputKey[0][0] in (1, 2):
```

Note that, if your `InputKey[0][0]` is of type `string`, you can convert it to `int` using `int(InputType[0][0])`, else it won't match with `1` or `2`.

Apart from that, your `for` loop can be modified as:

```
for line in input_key.readlines():         
    # You don't need list comprehension. `line.split()` itself gives a list
    InputKey.append(line.split())
```

Comment: I've tried both your suggestions but I'm getting the fail print I have set up. I'm printing the InputKey[0][0] value to confirm that it's being read properly and it's returning a `1`, but I'm still seeing fail.

Comment: How do you get that it fails? What output you get? what did you expected?

Comment: I have it as above, only I've edited an `else` statement which says (basically) 'failed'.

Comment: Well, if your `InputKey[0][0] is one out of `1` or `2`, the condition I posted would work. If it doesn't there is probably something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Got it working. I needed to wrap my integer expectations in quotes as python initially will interpret them as strings (I assume).

Comment: @Matt. Yup. If you had the list of string, then you will get string out only. You can use `int()` function to covert string to int.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just gonna edit it that last bit of info I discovered. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`if InputKey[0][0] == 1 or 2:` is the same as:

```
(InputKey[0][0] == 1) or (2)
```

And `2` is considered `True` (`bool(2) is True`), thus this will statement will always be True.

You want python to interpret this as:

```
InputKey[0][0] == 1 or InputKey[0][0] == 2
```

Or even:

```
InputKey[0][0] in [1, 2]
```